# Detox build failed - ':react-native-inappbrowser-reborn:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'

Tags: react-native, testing, detox

I have a problem with building tests in detox. It shows me this error:

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-inappbrowser-reborn:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module' from inputs:
> - /home/sp/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4f539c328e5bb19593050e3384e51919/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar
> - /home/sp/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/c1d521098bb09d070895b1fa3c6468bd/transformed/jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar
> Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
> https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
> for more information

I've tried almost everything I found on the forums:
kotlin.stdlib.jdk.variants.version.alignment=false

exclude("META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module")

exclude("META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7.kotlin_module")

exclude("META-INF/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8.kotlin_module")

exclude("META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module")

exclude("kotlin/annotation/annotation.kotlin_builtins")

exclude("kotlin/collections/collections.kotlin_builtins")

exclude("kotlin/coroutines/coroutines.kotlin_builtins")

exclude("kotlin/internal/internal.kotlin_builtins")

exclude("kotlin/kotlin.kotlin_builtins")

exclude("kotlin/ranges/ranges.kotlin_builtins")

exclude("kotlin/reflect/reflect.kotlin_builtins")

etc...

I got this error after adding:     implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0")) - > in app/build.gradle

I had to add this line because the whole application was not building. After adding this line, the problem discussed above started to appear in detox
Thank you very much for your help